Do Kotlin's List/Array data structures have a findSublist method analogous to String.indexOf(CharSequence)?
Do Kotlin's List/Array data structures have a findSublist method analogous to String.indexOf(CharSequence), that takes a List/Array/Sequence to match against the list?

While both operations are similar in nature, somehow most languages support it for strings and very few support it for collections. The reason may be that it is uncommon to do this for collections, while it is a very common operation for strings. Also, chars are very easy to compare and we can even do some optimizations by utilizing the fact they can be processed as numbers. Collections require to use equals for all comparisons. I suppose above reasons make it not very practical to include such operation in the stdlib and I believe Kotlin doesn't support it.
If you look for the most elegant or idiomatic solution, it could be:
fun <T> List<T>.findSublist(sublist: List<T>) = asSequence()
    .windowed(sublist.size) { it }
    .indexOf(sublist)

It is probably suboptimal for the performance, but mostly because of the overhead of sequences and keeping it object-oriented. Technically, it does a similar thing to a more optimized version where we iterate over indexes manually.
Please note windowed doesn't actually create a new sublist with each iteration. It uses a sliding window, so with each iteration we get exactly the same object with updated contents. For the same reason we are generally not allowed to pass it anywhere as it holds a temporary snapshot of the data. I believe the above solution is fine, because we use a sequence, so the execution flow alternates between the producer (windowed) and the consumer (indexOf).

Out of curiosity, why asSequence(). and not this. ? Byond Kotlinism, this is likely to be O(n*m) where n and m are list sizes.

If we don't switch to a sequence, it will have to create a list of all possible sublists, only then we search in it. By using a sequence, we create sublists as we iterate over the list. Worst time is the same: O(n*m), but the best/average should be better as we iterate only as much as we need to. Also, we save some memory for keeping the list of sublists.

@DavidSoroko In practice, there is some overhead related to sequences, so it may be even slower in some cases, especially if often the sublist cannot be found. But generally speaking, it is good to at least consider sequences in such cases.

Ah, I see that windowed also creates a sequence

@DavidSoroko While writing a comment to you, I realized I actually made a mistake in the solution. I expected the code doesn't actually create all these sublists, it doesn't copy the data, because windowed only creates views over the original list/seq. This is not true, internally it uses a sliding window and in my initial solution we actually was doing a lot of data copying. I updated the answer and added an explanation.

And by using this solution we have to use sequences. Without asSequence we can no longer leak it as that would produce a list of exactly the same sublist duplicated multiple times.

Maybe... for small enough lists it may not matter and for long enough lists, O(m*n) performance will make it unacceptable even with your latest changes.

@DavidSoroko So do you mean you actually expected better than O(m*n)? I would not expect a better performance even if went for a more "low-level" solution with managing indexes/iterators manually. Is there any known and relatively simple algorithm for this which doesn't go O(m*n)?

We could potentially go O(m+n) by utilizing the fact in Java/Kotlin we have the hashCode method and by supporting only objects with correctly implemented this method. We could keep a sliding hash and do equals only on match. But this is really far from the initial question.

There are hundreds of algorithms that find substring of a string better then brute force. I guess most of them can be adjusted to the case of lists

@DavidSoroko I'm not sure comparing strings and collections makes too much sense. Strings consist of chars: small and flat pieces of data, which we know, we can easily compare, convert to integers, and optimize in many ways. With lists the only capability we have is to compare one specific item to another specific item and this is it. And even if A == B and A == C, that doesn't necessarily mean A == C. It is hard to avoid comparing if comparing is the only capability we have. Again, if we trust hashCode, we could potentially use it, but this is a little unusual outside of hash maps, etc.

And this is not really a question about finding the fastest possible way to do X. The brute force algorithm, as you called it, is still m+n by average.

The question is close enough to it's string version to allow you to take advantage of many of the existing algorithms and their implementations.
An example, no claims about production readiness of end result:

Start with an existing Java implementation here,from Geeks for Geeks of the Knuth–Morris–Pratt (KMP) algorithm
Let IntelliJ auto convert to Kotlin
Replace references to String with List<T> + the necessary minor tweaks.

fun <T> List<T>.findSublistKMP(sublist: List<T>): List<Int> {
    
    fun computeLPSArray(sublist: List<T>, lps: IntArray) {
        var len = 0
        var i = 1
        lps[0] = 0

        while (i < sublist.size) {
            if (sublist[i] == sublist[len]) {
                len++
                lps[i] = len
                i++
            } else
            {
                if (len != 0) {
                    len = lps[len - 1]
                } else  // if (len == 0)
                {
                    lps[i] = len
                    i++
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val result = mutableListOf<Int>()

    val lps = IntArray(sublist.size)
    var j = 0

    computeLPSArray(sublist, lps)

    var i = 0
    while (i < this.size) {
        if (sublist[j] == this[i]) {
            j++
            i++
        }
        if (j == sublist.size) {
            result.add(i - j)
            j = lps[j - 1]
        } else if (i < this.size && sublist[j] != this[i]) {
            if (j != 0) j = lps[j - 1]
            else i += 1
        }
    }
    return result
}

Test code:

fun main() {
    data class Dat(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String = "$id is my name",
        val date: LocalDate = LocalDate.parse("2023-12-12")
    )

    val list = List(1_000) { i -> Dat(i) }
    val listX2 = list + list
    val sublist = listX2.subList(800, 900)

    listX2.findSublistKMP(sublist).also { println("KMP matches:$it") }
    // prints: KMP matches:[800, 1800]
}

